# PHP json_decode with long strings and special characters

Tags: php, json, regex, string

I am receiving a JSON response from an API server. The response varies in number of results and may contain several keys with long strings. These long strings may also contain special characters.

This is my sample array after json_decode:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1535497 [tid] => 6970000 [text] => Hello :) error is back! It's quite annoying! [dFlag] => 1 [iFlag] => [rFlag] => [member] => [contact] => Array ( [id] => 187 [name] => User Name [_info] => Array ( [contact_href] => https://url/187 ) ) [cFlag] => [processNotifications] => [dateCreated] => 2015-12-08T13:59:19Z [createdBy] => User Name user@domain.com (email) [iFlag] => [eFlag] => 1 [_info] => Array ( [lastUpdated] => 2015-12-08T13:59:19Z [updatedBy] => User Name user@domain.com (email) ) ) )
Array ( [1] => Array ( [id] => 1535499 [tid] => 6970000 [text] => Hello. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem ipsum. [dFlag] => 1 [iFlag] => [rFlag] => [member] => [contact] => Array ( [id] => 187 [name] => User Name [_info] => Array ( [contact_href] => https://url/187 ) ) [cFlag] => [processNotifications] => [dateCreated] => 2015-12-08T13:59:19Z [createdBy] => User Name user@domain.com (email) [iFlag] => [eFlag] => 1 [_info] => Array ( [lastUpdated] => 2015-12-08T13:59:19Z [updatedBy] => User Name user@domain.com (email) ) ) )
```

You can see where it breaks in the array beautifier: http://phillihp.com/toolz/php-array-beautifier/

**For instance, some strings contain a ':)', therefore when I apply json_decode($response,true), the converted array breaks due to the closed parenthesis contained in the string.**

The only way I have seen this to be a *possible solution* was to use a separate function (sample below) and a regex query, but it seems like overhead. Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

```
<?php
function json_clean_decode($json, $assoc = false, $depth = 512, $options = 0) {
// sample regex
  $json = preg_replace("#(/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/)|([\s\t]//.*)|(^//.*)#", '', $json);

  if(version_compare(phpversion(), '5.4.0', '>=')) {
        $json = json_decode($json, $assoc, $depth, $options);
  }
  elseif(version_compare(phpversion(), '5.3.0', '>=')) {
        $json = json_decode($json, $assoc, $depth);
  } else {
        $json = json_decode($json, $assoc);
  }

  return $json;
  }
?>
```

I imagine there must be another way to deal with long strings and special characters decoded from json.

TIA

Comment: JSON doesn't have any comments, if your has, its a custom protocol and not real JSON

Comment: That is just a sample function. The regex can be changed to something else, i.e. to find :). I am trying to find an alternative method to deal with long strings and parentheses in these strings.

Comment: **Real valid json** can have any characters in any order. If now something breaks your array (I can't even imagine how) it's not a json.

Comment: Can you try using add_slashes() to the json first, and then using json_decode?

Comment: What API are you getting the JSON response from?   If it's not quoting the string values in the response, it's invalid JSON.   In such a case, as you suspect, manual effort may be required to convert the non-JSON data to JSON data.

Comment: thomasw_lrd: addslashes function expects a string - throws an error

Comment: I just checked the response and the json output strings are enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: Please note that we are looking at output of `print_r`. Don't expect that output to adhere to some syntax! It is not JSON. The JSON representation of the same would have no problems at all, and all strings would be quoted, avoiding any misinterpretation of parentheses. If there is any problem here, it is with this beautifier, but nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem with the decoded JSON you provide the `print_r` output of: the key *iFlag* appears twice in the same object. This should not be possible.

The original JSON string you decoded would have looked like this:

```php
$json = '[
    {
        "id": 1535497,
        "tid": 6970000,
        "text": "Hello :) error is back! It\'s quite annoying!",
        "dFlag": 1,
        "iFlag": null,
        "rFlag": null,
        "member": null,
        "contact": {
            "id": 187,
            "name": "User Name",
            "_info": {
                "contact_href": "https:\/\/url\/187"
            }
        },
        "iFlag": null,
        "cFlag": null,
        "processNotifications": null,
        "dateCreated": "2015-12-08T13:59:19Z",
        "createdBy": "User Name user@domain.com (email)",
        "eFlag": 1,
        "_info": {
            "lastUpdated": "2015-12-08T13:59:19Z",
            "updatedBy": "User Name user@domain.com (email)"
        }
    }
]';
```

And indeed, if I decode and print it like this:

```
$data = json_decode($json, true); // translate objects to associative arrays
print_r ($data);
```

...the output is the same as you provided in the question, with the exception of the duplicate *iFlag* property:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1535497 [tid] => 6970000 [text] => Hello :) error is back! It's quite annoying! [dFlag] => 1 [iFlag] => [rFlag] => [member] => [contact] => Array ( [id] => 187 [name] => User Name [_info] => Array ( [contact_href] => https://url/187 ) ) [cFlag] => [processNotifications] => [dateCreated] => 2015-12-08T13:59:19Z [createdBy] => User Name user@domain.com (email) [eFlag] => 1 [_info] => Array ( [lastUpdated] => 2015-12-08T13:59:19Z [updatedBy] => User Name user@domain.com (email) ) ) )
```

That the array beautifier breaks on this, just means that this beautifier is not good enough. It tries to interpret the output of `print_r`, but apparently it has some weaknesses. This however is no indication that there is a problem with JSON encoding/decoding.

`print_r` does in fact a good job in "beautifying" the output itself, but in a browser context you need to preserve the formatting to see it, e.g. by wrapping that output in `pre` tags. If you do, you'll see this output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1535497
            [tid] => 6970000
            [text] => Hello :) error is back! It's quite annoying!
            [dFlag] => 1
            [iFlag] => 
            [rFlag] => 
            [member] => 
            [contact] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 187
                    [name] => User Name
                    [_info] => Array
                        (
                            [contact_href] => https://url/187
                        )

                )

            [cFlag] => 
            [processNotifications] => 
            [dateCreated] => 2015-12-08T13:59:19Z
            [createdBy] => User Name user@domain.com (email)
            [eFlag] => 1
            [_info] => Array
                (
                    [lastUpdated] => 2015-12-08T13:59:19Z
                    [updatedBy] => User Name user@domain.com (email)
                )

        )

)
```

Now we could JSON encode that data again:

```php
$json = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo $json;
```

The output is the original JSON, except for the duplicate object member. There are no other problems:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1535497,
        "tid": 6970000,
        "text": "Hello :) error is back! It's quite annoying!",
        "dFlag": 1,
        "iFlag": null,
        "rFlag": null,
        "member": null,
        "contact": {
            "id": 187,
            "name": "User Name",
            "_info": {
                "contact_href": "https:\/\/url\/187"
            }
        },
        "cFlag": null,
        "processNotifications": null,
        "dateCreated": "2015-12-08T13:59:19Z",
        "createdBy": "User Name user@domain.com (email)",
        "eFlag": 1,
        "_info": {
            "lastUpdated": "2015-12-08T13:59:19Z",
            "updatedBy": "User Name user@domain.com (email)"
        }
    }
]
```

Now this you can decode again:

```php
$back = json_decode($json);
print_r ($back);
```

The output is again the original `print_r` output you provided, except for the duplicate member. So there is no problem with JSON encoding whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks! I modified the array before posting and made a typo. Perhaps the beautifier is what's misleading. I'll try the Pre tags. Thanks again!

Comment: The issue was with the beautifier afterall. Using the <pre> tags helped me fix the issue.